# Bank conflict in CUDA when reading from the same location

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA kernel where there is a point where each thread is reading the same value from the global memory. So something like:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(const float4 * key_pts)
{
    if (key_pts[blockIdx.x] < 0 return;
}
```

The kernel is configured as follows:

```
dim3 blocks(16, 16);
dim3 grid(2000);
my_kernel<<<grid, blocks, 0, stream>>>(key_pts);
```

My question is whether this will lead to some sort bank conflict or sub-optimal access in CUDA. I must confess I do not understand this issue in detail yet.

I was thinking I could do something like the following in case we have sub-optimal access:

```
__global__ void my_kernel(const float4 * key_pts)
{
    __shared__ float x;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
        x = key_pts[blockIdx.x];

    __syncthreads();

    if (x < 0) return;
}
```

Doing some timing though, I do not see any difference between the two but so far my tests are with limited data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bank conflicts apply to [shared memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-2-x), not global memory.

Since all threads need (ultimately) the same value to make their decision, this won't yield sub-optimal access on global memory because there is a *broadcast mechanism* so that all threads in the same warp, requesting the same location/value from [global memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-2-x), will retrieve that without any serialization or overhead.  All threads in the warp can be serviced at the same time:

> Note that threads can access any words in any order, including the same words.

Furthermore, assuming your GPU has a cache (cc2.0 or newer) the value retrieved from global memory for the first warp encountering this will likely be available in the cache for subsequent warps that hit this point.

I wouldn't expect much performance difference between the two cases.